# Doubt of gauge covariant derivatives: how can I derive it?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory, differentiation

In the context of general relativity (GR) it is necessary to introduce the notion of covariant derivatives. From the point of view of a basic introduction, we always start to deal with GR in a highly chart-dependent exposition.

Now, in order to *derive* the covariant derivative we can simply ask ourselves what is the derivative of a vector field **$V$**. In other words, we derive the covariant derivative as:

> $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\mu}}\Big(V^{\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}}\Big) = \frac{\partial V^{\nu} }{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}}+ V^{\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\mu}}\Big(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}}\Big) \implies $$
>
> $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \Bigg(\frac{\partial V^{\nu} }{\partial x^{\mu}}+ \Gamma^{\nu}\hspace{0.1mm}_{\mu\alpha} V^{\alpha}\Bigg)\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}} := \nabla_{\mu}V^{\nu}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{\nu}}  \tag{1}$$
> Therefore we have *derived* the covariant derivative:
>
> $$\nabla_{\mu}V^{\nu} = \frac{\partial V^{\nu} }{\partial x^{\mu}}+ \Gamma^{\nu}\hspace{0.1mm}_{\mu\alpha} V^{\alpha} \tag{2}$$

**I would like to know: **how can I derive the (gauge) covariant derivative given by $(3)$ using more mathematical arguments than physical ones?**** :

> $$D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} - iqA_{\mu} \tag{3}$$

Comment: Perhaps add the gauge group definition as well? I think the gauge derivative depends on which gauge group you are interested in.

Comment: @Emil The general form (up to conventions) does not depend on the specific group.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory_(mathematics))

Comment: @NDewolf: in wikipedia the standard model had three terms instead of one with different charges not just q. So I don't believe what is written here is the general form you speak of in that case.

Comment: In fact, since it has an electromagnetism tag, my guess is it is $U(1)$.

Comment: @Emil That is simply because the Standard Model has the gauge group $U(1)\times SU(2)\times SU(3)$ (up to minor group theoretic issues) and as such the connection can be decomposed in three terms. Nothing keeps you from writing it as one big connection term (which is the general case).

Comment: @NDewolf: I think the q is very misleading in that case, it would be better with a tensor contraction with a tensor that contains all different charges or no q at all.

Comment: @Emil That's not the point, the general form does not contain such a contraction, that only happens in the case where the connection can be decomposed. Of course one can absorb the overall factor $q$, but this is just a convention.

Comment: @NDewolf: the q is not the factor for electric charge in general case is my point. Better to absorb it in the vector than have a random scalar in front. I don't know why you ignore my point.